# Update menu item after screen rotation

Tags: android, android-asynctask, menuitem, screen-rotation

I'd like to show a progress bar when a user clicks a menu item in the action bar and launch an AsyncTask that does some work. When finished the task restore the menu. Here is my code:

```
public class DevicesActivity extends FragmentActivity {
...

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {   
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.my_menu_action:
                MyTask task = new MyTask();
                task.execute(item);
                // Show a progress bar instead of default actionview
                item.setActionView(R.layout.progress_circle);
                item.expandActionView();
                return true;
         }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
     }

    ...

    private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<MenuItem, Object, Object> {
        MenuItem menuItem;

        protected Object doInBackground(MenuItem... items) {
            item = items[0];

            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {}

            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
            // Restore default action view
            if (menuItem != null) {
                menuItem.collapseActionView();
                menuItem.setActionView(null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem occurs when the activity is recreated (for example when rotating the screen) because the progress bar isn't shown and the menuItem reference inside MyTask becomes invalid. So the questions are:
1) When creating the menu (onCreateOptionsMenu method) how can I know if the menuItem was clicked ?
2) In onPostExecute how can I retrieve a valid reference to a MenuItem object ?

Answer (score 0):

Read about the use of following methods

```
onCreateOptionsMenu
onPrepareOptionsMenu
onOptionsItemSelected
invalidateOptionsMenu
```

Now, when you click on an item, from onOptionsItemSelected save a reference to the item clicked. Next start the AsyncTask and show ProgressBar. When finished with task, to update menu items call invalidateOptionsMenu from onPostExceute of your AsyncTask.

You can save the state (visible/invisible) of menuItem using `onSaveInstanceState()`  just before screen config changes, etc and re-create from `savedInstanceBundle`.

You must have the logic to show/hide menu items in onPrepareOptionsMenu. Whenever you want to update your menu items, call invalidateOptionsMenu.

Hope it gives you a direction.

Comment: How do you simply save the MenuItem reference within the onSaveInstanceState bundle? I tried casting it to a serializable, but that doesn't work.

Comment: I was wrong, I should say "save the state of menu item" and not the reference to menu item.